# in odoo16 owl, how to store current page state after go to another page, and restore them when back to this page from the breadcrumbs?

Tags: odoo-16

I created a "ir.actions.client" component just like:  (just simple example, pls ignore the coding errors, just help to explain my question)

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
static template = xml`
    <input t-model="params_test">
    <t foreach="results" t-as="val" t-key="val">
        <t t-esc="val"/>
    </t>
`;
   setup() {...}
   this.params_test = useState("");
   this.results = useState([]); 
   dosomething(){  ...  }
}
TestComponent.template = "test_template";
registry.category("actions").add("testcomponent", TestComponent);
```

from this page, I submit parameter and get the values from backend, and render the "results" to the page.
then I select on record of results and click it to its detailed page(actually it's in another module),
after that when I click back to the "TestComponent" page, all results disappeared, also without the parameter i submitted --- it's just a initial page.

My question, how to store the "TestComponent" page state when go to another page, and can find them when back to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer closed.
the solution: use localstorage